# How to mask an UIimage with UIColor?

Tags: iphone, core-graphics, quartz-2d

I wish to mask an `UIimage` with `UIColor`. Refer to the code below. Its not working for me. *I am trying to mask light to mid-‐range brown colors in the image.*

> `ivMasking1` is source `Imageview`.

Code:

```
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(ivMasking1.frame.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    const CGFloat myMaskingColors[6] = {124, 255,  68, 222, 0, 165};
    CGImageRef myColorMaskedImage = CGImageCreateWithMaskingColors (ivMasking1.image.CGImage,
                                                         myMaskingColors);
    CGRect myContextRect = CGRectMake(0,0,50,50);

    CGContextDrawImage (context, myContextRect, myColorMaskedImage);

    ivMasking2 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()];
    ivMasking2.frame = CGRectMake(0 ,125, 300,200);
    ivMasking2.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    ivMasking2.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:ivMasking2];
```

Thanks!
P.S. : You may refer to the topic: **Masking an Image with Color** from **[Quartz Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/Introduction/Introduction.html)**

Comment: what you want?? i think you want to save the image with brown color mask right??

Comment: True !
Dear @Paras , Please refer to the programming guide page 160 - Listing 11-3 Figure 11-11.Hope this clarifies my question :)